# How to get current camera parameters in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

How can I get the current camera parameters in pyqtgraph? The code below launches a window and I can move and rotate the camera but the docs doesn't tell me how I can get the camera parameters. If there are any hotkeys to get it.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl

from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
g = gl.GLGridItem(size=QtGui.QVector3D(100,100,1),color=(255, 255, 0, 100))
w.addItem(g)    
w.show()    
app.exec()
```

the functions `orbit(azim, elev)` and `pan(dx, dy, dz, relative='global')` from https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3dgraphics/glviewwidget.html let me set the camera position but how can I obtain them while the screen is launched?

i.e. I want to launch the screen, move the camera to a position I like, then store the azim, elev, dx ,dy, dz for use next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain Camera parameters with `cameraPrams()` method.
Here is short code snippet based on Your code.

```
import sys

import PyQt5
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph.opengl import GLViewWidget, GLGridItem


class PrintCameraWidget(GLViewWidget):
    """Small ViewWidget which prints camera parameters"""

    def wheelEvent(self, ev):
        """Update view on zoom event"""
        super().wheelEvent(ev)
        self.get_camera_view()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        """Update view on move event"""
        super().mouseMoveEvent(ev)
        self.get_camera_view()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        """Update view on move event"""
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(ev)
        self.get_camera_view()

    def get_camera_view(self):
        camera_params = self.cameraParams()
        print("New camera parameters: ", camera_params)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrintCameraWidget()
    g = GLGridItem(size=QtGui.QVector3D(100, 100, 1), color=(255, 255, 0, 100))
    w.addItem(g)

    # Create and set Camera parameters
    camera_params = {'rotation': PyQt5.QtGui.QQuaternion(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                     'distance': 10.0,
                     'fov': 60}
    w.setCameraParams(**camera_params)
    print("Initial camera parameters: ", w.cameraParams())

    w.show()
    app.exec()
```